# Java Open Telemetry Class Loading Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, dockerfile, open-telemetry

I have a spring boot java project, which has a open telemetry jar. The service is packaged as a docker image and it is deployed on Kubernetes.

When the service starts, this open telemetry jar tries to instantiate okHttpClient internally and fails. This instantiation in the open telemetry jar doesn't seem have retry limits, so it tries to load the class repeatedly. Eventually, the service shutsdown with OutOfMemoryError.

This behavior is sporadic. For eg - if there are multiple instances of the service running, occasionally 1 or 2 instances fail with this error. But when these instances are killed and restarted the issue doesn't come up again.

Also, the issue could not be replicated in the developer machines.

Can someone please give me pointers on how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting an `OutOfMemoryError`, I'd recommend using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and then analyzing the heap dump in Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer, specifically looking at the leak suspect report.